# RXJS throttletime operator is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, throttling, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a method that is making http calls to the server. this method is being called like 500 times and leading page to crash. I want to separate the calls and make a 200ms delay between calls. I thought of using throttletime operator but it it is not working.

```
testSubject: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();


testMethod(id){
   for(let i = 0; i < 500; i++){
     this.testSubject.next(this.counter);
     this.testSubject.pipe(throttleTime(200)).subscribe(
        (data:any) =>{
           return this.addRow(groupId);        
         }
        )
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

I expect the code above to work as follow:

- counter gets incremented by 1
- Subject.next() fires to update the subject with the new value
- Adding the `throttletime` when subscribing to the `testSubject`. so it should make 200ms delay

Comment: ... but that's not what throttling is/does. Also: you're subscribing 500 times and giving each subscription it's own throttleTime

Comment: @MrkSef do you have a suggestion what to use in this case?

Comment: What is this.addRow? What does that return? A promise/observable?

Comment: @MrkSef this is the method that is making the http call. it is returning json data

Comment: Can you show the code for that? How are you telling it to wait for the response from the server in order to get the JSON?

Comment: @MrkSef  I mean if throttle is not supposed to be used for this scenario. what else should i use?

Comment: Just use concat or concatMap if you want one request to finish before the next one starts, or use mergeMap with a concurrency limit if you want only a certain number of concurrent calls in a row. But to do that you need to expose when the underlying request starts and finishes, hens the question of how you implemented `this.addRow`

Comment: does this.addRow sends an HTTP request and returns an `observable`?

Comment: @MrkSef it calls another function that sends the request and returns an observable

Comment: @HassanMoin yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you might use concatMap to ensure only one request (to `addRow`) runs at a time.

```ts
// The Settup
const testSubject: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
testSubject.pipe(

  concatMap(_ => this.addRow(groupId))

).subscribe(JSONdataFromAddRow => {/* Do nothing */});


// Triggering 500 calls
let counter = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 500; i++){
  testSubject.next(counter);
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, you can use `concatMap` if you want to wait for the request to finish until you want to send the next one. Use `range` instead of the `for` loop to iterate 500 times.

```js
range(1, 500).pipe(
     concatMap(() => {
     return this.yourHttpService.addRow(groupId).pipe(throttleTime(200));
    })
   )
   .subscribe(() => {
     console.log('HTTP successful requests');
   });
```

This will repeat HTTP requests after successful completion and 200ms delay if the request completes before 200ms.